# How do I modify this Google formula to filter out blank responses from Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-custom-function, google-sheets-addons, form-mule

I have Google Sheets running the add-on Form Mule to automatically send emails with the responses to a Google Form. Using the following formula, I was able to get a nice HTML table to show up in the body of each email.

```
=RANGETOTABLE(FILTER(D:AH,A:A=A2),$D$1:$AH$1)
```

This returns a table that looks like this:

[image: Blank cells and a single response cell]

I want to try and filter the cells with nothing in them, out, so that only cells with values in them are returned.

Comment: Now the question doesn't make sense. If you selectively drop cells from each row, that's not a table anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You can include multiple conditions in a filter by using multiplication (which means logical AND). For example,

```
FILTER(D:AH, (A:A=A2) * LEN(E:E) * LEN(H:H))
```

requires A to be equal to A2 **and** E to be nonempty **and** H to be nonempty.

Conditions can also be combined using addition, which stands for logical OR:

```
FILTER(D:AH, (A:A=A2) * (LEN(E:E) + LEN(H:H)))
```

requires A to be equal to A2 **and** that either E **or** H be nonempty.

If you have a lot of columns (like D:AH), one of which must be nonempty, the formula will have to be somewhat long. Instead of adding lengths as above, one can use concatenation `&` to shorten it a bit:

```
FILTER(D:AH, (A:A=A2) * LEN(E:E & F:F & G:G & H:H & I:I & J:J & K:K & L:L & M:M & N:N & O:O & P:P & Q:Q & R:R & S:S & T:T & U:U & V:V & W:W & X:X & Y:Y & Z:Z & AA:AA & AB:AB & AC:AC & AD:AD & AE:AE & AF:AF & AG:AG & AH:AH))`
```

Long, but you only have to do it once.

---

By the way, I used a spreadsheet to generate the long string above, by making a column of letters (say, in A1:A30) and then using `=join(" & ", arrayformula(A1:A30 & ":" & A1:A30))`)

Comment: So could I just do:  =RANGETOTABLE(FILTER(D:AH,A:A=A2 * LEN(D:AH)),$D$1:$AH$1) in order to only return responses that are non-empty? Did I place it correctly?

Comment: Unfortunately, `LEN` won't work with a two-dimensional array like that. See my edit.

Comment: To isolate the problem, try the FILTER formula on its own, without Rangetotable.

Comment: Since I know D1:AH1 will always have something (as they are the headers) I only really need it to return a result when D2:AH2 have responses. But it is possible then to remove the column altogether without jacking up the ordering?

Comment: The filter removes the __rows__ not columns. A row is dropped if all of the cells D-AH in that row are empty. If this is not what you wanted, edit the question with a more specific explanation of what you want.

Comment: I'm sorry. I will edit my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can include in your formula something like A:A<>"" that way it will ignore values in column A that are blank.

So:
`=RANGETOTABLE(FILTER(D:AH,A:A=A2,A:A<>""),$D$1:$AH$1)`