# Filter out blank responses in columns using Form Mule

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-addons, google-sheets-form-submissions, form-mule

I currently have a response form where people are submitting requests for different items. Not every item is requested every time. The end goal is to automatically have them receive an email with a list of each item they requested after submitting the form.

Using `=rangetoverticaltable` from Form Mule, a Google Sheets add-on, you get a pretty table as below

[image]

The end goal is to get the same table returned but with the "water" column being filtered out as it is blank, i.e.:

[image]

I've read [this post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/96029/how-do-i-modify-this-google-formula-to-filter-out-blank-responses-from-google-sh) multiple times and I can't seem to figure out if the answer at the end of the post closes with it isn't possible or I'm missing a step.
 I am currently using the formula
 `=arrayformula(if(not(isblank(A$2:A)),RANGETOVERTICALTABLE(FILTER($A$2:$E,A$2:A=A$2),$A$1:$E$1),""))`
and this generates the first table as shown.

What can I add into the filter() section to remove the rows that have empty cells in column B?

The link to the google sheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10jXvND6MLaPWk1kwzWiBOWZk9eNghpAEgOK5JvKWy00/edit#gid=1961786966).

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome. Please try to use FILTER or QUERY (built-in functions) using `rangetoverticaltable` as the first argument of them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have been more clear in where I am getting stuck.
I am currently using the formula =arrayformula(if(not(isblank(A$2:A)),RANGETOVERTICALTABLE(FILTER($A$2:$E,A$2:A=A$2),$A$1:$E$1),"")) and this generates the first  table as shown.
What can I add into the filter() section to remove the rows that have empty cells in column B?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add the all the relevant details.

Comment: Done, thanks for the advice.

Comment: If all you're looking to do is add a condition to the FILTER statement, you could just add `,$B$2:$B<>""` just before the closing parentheses on FILTER()